# Changing type of ActiveRecord Class in Rails with Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I have two types of classes:

```
BaseUser < ActiveRecord::Base
```

and

```
User < BaseUser
```

which acts_as_authentic using Authlogic's authentication system. This inheritance is implemented using Single Table Inheritance

If a new user registers, I register him as a User. However, if I already have a BaseUser with the same email, I'd like to change that BaseUser to a User in the database without simply copying all the data over to the User from the BaseUser and creating a new User (i.e. with a new id). Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just set the type field to 'User' and save the record. The in-memory object will still show as a BaseUser but the next time you reload the in-memory object will be a User

```
>> b=BaseUser.new
>> b.class # = BaseUser

# Set the Type. In-Memory object is still a BaseUser
>> b.type='User'
>> b.class # = BaseUser
>> b.save

# Retrieve the records through both models (Each has the same class)

>> User.find(1).class # = User
>> BaseUser.find(1).class # User
```

Comment: your answer is working fine for me but it is not running the validations of `User` class, can you please help me with that?

Comment: @abhas if you want to have model validation, you will need to add '!' to the end. This enforces validation, and is common convention. i.e. create!, find_by!, save!

Comment: See the better answer from @balexand below

Answer (score 103):

Steve's answer works but since the instance is of class `BaseUser` when `save` is called, validations and callbacks defined in `User` will not run. You'll probably want to convert the instance using the [becomes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes) method:

```
user = BaseUser.where(email: "user@example.com").first_or_initialize
user = user.becomes(User) # convert to instance from BaseUser to User
user.type = "User"
user.save!
```

Comment: Experimenting with `rails c` in Rails 3.2.18, I didn't need to call `user.becomes` in order for the new class's validations to run. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: You can use `user = user.becomes!(User)` (with a `!`) and omit the `user.type = "User"` line.

Comment: This Is Terrific. Never heard of that method anywhere

Answer (score 5):

Based on the other answers, I expected this to work in Rails 4.1:

```
  def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    # This separate step is required to change Single Table Inheritance types
    new_type = params[:company][:type]
    if new_type != @company.type && Company::COMPANY_TYPES.include?(new_type)
      @company.becomes!(new_type.constantize)
      @company.type = new_type
      @company.save!
    end

    @company.update(company_params)
    respond_with(@company)
  end
```

It did not, as the type change would not persist. Instead, I went with this less elegant approach, which works correctly:

```
  def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    # This separate step is required to change Single Table Inheritance types
    new_type = params[:company][:type]
    if new_type != @company.type && Company::COMPANY_TYPES.include?(new_type)
      @company.update_column :type, new_type
    end

    @company.update(company_params)
    respond_with(@company)
  end
```

And here are the controller tests I used to confirm the solution:

```
  describe 'Single Table Inheritance (STI)' do

    class String
      def articleize
        %w(a e i o u).include?(self[0].to_s.downcase) ? "an #{self}" : "a #{self}"
      end
    end

    Company::COMPANY_TYPES.each do |sti_type|
      it "a newly assigned Company of type #{sti_type} " \
        "should be #{sti_type.articleize}" do
        post :create, { company: attributes_for(:company, type: sti_type) },
             valid_session
        expect(assigns(:company)).to be_a(sti_type.constantize)
      end
    end

    Company::COMPANY_TYPES.each_index do |i|
      sti_type, next_sti_type = Company::COMPANY_TYPES[i - 1],
                                Company::COMPANY_TYPES[i]
      it "#{sti_type.articleize} changed to type #{next_sti_type} " \
        "should be #{next_sti_type.articleize}" do
        company = Company.create! attributes_for(:company, type: sti_type)
        put :update, { id: company.to_param, company: { type: next_sti_type } },
            valid_session
        reloaded_company = Company.find(company.to_param)
        expect(reloaded_company).to be_a(next_sti_type.constantize)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, with one small change: 

`new_type = params[:listing][:type]
    if new_type != @listing.type && Listing::LISTING_TYPES.include?(new_type)
      # we're changing class types here, so need to be careful
      @listing.update_column :type, new_type
      @listing = new_type.constantize.find(@listing.id)
    end`

I needed to reload the instance manually (calling "reload" didn't work in my case)