# Rails STI change type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, sti

I am currently working on a project where I am using an STI model and wish to convert one record into another type without creating a new record. There are observers which are hooked up to fire on create of a new model, however I don't want these observers to fire and would like to maintain the same ID. Is there an easy way of converting the record from one model to another through the ORM?, without using SQL?

Cheers

Comment: Do you have a base model?  For instance bear, cat, dog are all mammals?  If so, you can use that model and just do an update attribute to change the type flag.  Can you share your models with us?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing type of ActiveRecord Class in Rails with Single Table Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262415/changing-type-of-activerecord-class-in-rails-with-single-table-inheritance)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3262415/41283

Answer (score 3):

[`#becomes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes) can do what you want:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Bar < Foo
end

class Baz < Foo
end

baz = Baz.create({})
bar = baz.becomes(Bar)
```

At that point, you'll still have the `baz` record in the `foos` table. You'll have to make sure saving `bar` doesn't cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

`becomes!` did not work for me, as detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26091638/1935918 . Instead, I recommend using `update_column`:

```
  def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    # This separate step is required to change Single Table Inheritance types
    new_type = params[:company][:type]
    if new_type != @company.type && Company::COMPANY_TYPES.include?(new_type)
      @company.update_column :type, new_type
    end

    @company.update(company_params)
    respond_with(@company)
  end
```